# Шифрование методом плейфера с++

Tags: c++, шифрование, криптография

Просить написать программу - глупо(ну я и сам хочу ее написать), но я споткнулся на моменте когда нужно зашифровывать данные, не могу понять как это сделать, может кто подскажет, от чего надо отталкиваться(правила шифровки знаю, код написать не получается)

Comment: Ну [вот же](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#.D0.98.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.88.D0.B8.D1.84.D1.80.D0.B0_.D0.9F.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B9.D1.84.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0) хорошее описание.

Comment: А что именно не получается? Что вы пытались? Если сложно, попробуйте для начала например написать простую перестановку.

Comment: читал вики, я же писал, что вручную зашифровать расшифровать могу, а вот написать не получается, ну у меня уже имеется матрица 5х5 заполненная спереди ключевым словом, а дальше оставшимся алфавитом, имеется финальное слово которое нужно зашифровать...я просто не знаю как вылавливать биграммы и менять им буквы программно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот вам код.

Предполагая, что вы правильно заполнили матрицу 5x5 в двумерном массиве `mat[5, 5]`:

```
using namespace std;

string Encode(string cleartext)
{
    string result;
    char prev;
    bool hasPrev = false;
    for (char curr : cleartext)
    {
        if (!hasPrev) // ожидаем конца биграммы
        {
            prev = curr;
            hasPrev = true;
            continue;
        }
        char c1, c2;
        // правило 1
        if (prev == curr)
        {
            EncodePair(curr, 'X', result);
        }
        else
        {
            EncodePair(prev, curr, result);
            hasPrev = false;
        }
    }
    if (hasPrev)
        EncodePair(prev, 'X', result);
    return result;
}

void EncodePair(char prev, char curr, string& s)
{
    Index idxPrev = indexByChar[prev];
    Index idxCurr = indexByChar[curr];
    assert(idxPrev.Row != idxCurr.Row ||
           idxPrev.Col != idxCurr.Col);
    Index resPrev, resNext;
    if (idxPrev.Row == idxCurr.Row) // правило 2
    {
        resPrev = idxPrev.NextCol();
        resNext = idxNext.NextCol();
    }
    else if (idxPrev.Col == idxCurr.Col) // правило 3
    {
        resPrev = idxPrev.NextRow();
        resNext = idxNext.NextRow();
    }
    else // правило 4
    {
        resPrev = Index(idxPrev.Row, idxNext.Col);
        resNext = Index(idxNext.Row, idxPrev.Col);
    }
    s += matrix[resPrev.Row, resPrev.Col];
    s += matrix[resNext.Row, resNext.Col];
}
```

Вам придётся заполнить `map<char, Index>` `indexByChar`, чтобы по символу находить его строку и столбец в матрице (понятно, как?). Структура `Index` очевидна:

```
struct Index
{
    int Row;
    int Col;

    Index(int row, int col)
    {
        Row = row;
        Col = col;
    }

    static Index NextRow()
    {
        int r = (Row + 1) % 5;
        return Index(r, Col);
    }

    static Index NextCol()
    {
        int c = (Col + 1) % 5;
        return Index(Row, c);
    }
};
```

Comment: слишком продвинутый с++ для меня пока что, много непоняток...структуры пока я не понимаю зачем нужны, комбинация public static тоже не понятно, this тоже не знаю, что такое var?
что такое string Encode(всегда использовал char)
Конечно, понятно что это проблема не форума почему я не знаю, но код слишком крут для меня пока что

Comment: @MaximPro: Ой блин. Я написал на C# случайно. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @MaximPro: переделал. Теперь лучше?

Comment: Лучше, но мне непонятно объявление string, я всегда использую char, да и вопросы то почти прежние, я понимаю что это написано продвинуто,но увы я пока не смогу это разобрать, но так как вы помогли и сидели морочились с этим я принимаю ваш ответ

Comment: @MaximPro: На C++ следует использовать `std::string` вместо `char*`. Обязательно освойте его.